# Colocar amostra de códigos em um post do Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou começando a desenvolver um site para ensinar outras pessoas a programarem no Wordpress, gostaria de inserir de uma forma estilizada os códigos que irei disponibilizar nos posts, segue o exemplo do meu primeiro post:
http://www.pblog.com.br/inserindo-fontes-em-um-template-do-wordpress/

A forma que estou pensando é criar uma classe os códigos e estilizar no CSS, seria essa a melhor opção?

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para adicionar códigos-fonte de linguagens de programação em suas postagens, você pode utilizar um plugin de Syntax Highlight. Aqui tem um exemplo de um destes plugins:

https://www.linknacional.com.br/30/como-inserir-codigo-posts-wordpress/